# What's the safest, cleanest way to jailbreak my iPad 1?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

What's the safest, cleanest way to jailbreak my ipad1?

I'm running iOS 5 I believe.

Comment: Please choose an answer, for it's been a few months.

Comment: @Andrew Larsson I tried your answer and it broke Safari and the app store, so I just stopped bothering. Oh well I only ever use the ipad as an ereader/video machine anyway

Comment: Have you tried Googling this?Redsn0w works fine for ipad one. And mark that answer as answer please.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend redsn0w. It's what I used. It's not hard to do, plus it has a lot of other tools in it that can help if you mess up. The link to the official download and a quick tutorial can be found [here](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/14857834236/untethered-holidays). You'll need to upgrade to iOS 5.0.1 beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it myself, but [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-5.0.1-untethered-on-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-using-sn0wbreeze-2.9/) came to light after a quick [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/) search. Looking deeper it appears that this is the only untethered jailbreak available for A4 devices that doesn't first require a [tethered jailbreak](http://greenpois0n.com/?p=150).

Good luck.